Is there a way to mimic the Element.closest() function from javascript in Scrapy python?
I am trying to convert my web-scraper I built in JavaScript using the puppeteer library into a python-based web-scraper running on Scrapy. I want to be able to do something similar to JavaScript's Element.closest() method to find the closest DOM element to the Element I run the function on. I haven't been able to find anything that does the same thing on Scrapy.
The line of JavaScript I am trying to mimic is below:
const menuSection = item.closest(".card-body").querySelector("h5").textContent.trim();

Where "item" is another DOM element and I am trying to find the closest DOM element with the classname of "card-body"
I have tried to figure out how to use xpaths to locate the closest DOM element of a certain classname, however, I couldn't figure out how to do it.

Use a loop that calls parentNode() until it finds the element you want or reaches the root.
